# How to use PIVOT table consisting of Datetime value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to convert rows into columns using PIVOT, one of the columns will has Date Time values as NVARCHAR(MAX), but I get this error
 "Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string."

Here is the table, The column type for [Value]  is NVARCHAR(MAX)

```
Id | ColumnName   | Value 
01 | EmployeeName | Tommy
02 | Id           | 5A477EC0-F6A9-4BD4-9B69-D4C8253E8E75
03 | StartDate    | Jun 27 2015 10:25PM
```

I am trying to covert the rows into columns and insert the Result into MyTable which is

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable (EmployeeName NVARCHAR(50) NULL, 
                [Id] UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NULL, 
                [StartDate] datetime NULL)

INSERT INTO MyTable ([EmployeeName],[Id],[StartDate]) 
SELECT [EmployeeName],[Id],[StartDate]
FROM (
    SELECT Value, ColumnName
    FROM Employee ) x
PIVOT (
MAX(Value)
FOR ColumnName in ([EmployeeName],[Id],[StartDate])) p
```

The Expected Result in MyTable would look like

```
Id                                   | EmployeeName | StartDate
5A477EC0-F6A9-4BD4-9B69-D4C8253E8E75 | Tommy        | Jun 27 2015 10:25PM
```

Comment: Anukool this is strange, your query works well for me. Maybe there are other rows than the ones you mention who fail the query?

Comment: Is this query running on a different computer with a different regional setting ? If you really must store datetimes in a varchar, then ALWAYS use a region independant format. See http://karaszi.com/the-ultimate-guide-to-the-datetime-datatypes

Comment: @AnukoolGandhi . . . Your code appears to work when I try it:  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=430fc3d5c4c5c10ecfe6f3beb0c05782.

Comment: I had missed specifying that I am trying to input the result in another table which has a column of Datetime type, I have updated it above, sorry for the misunderstanding

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to reproduce your situation, however it works perfectly:

```
SELECT [EmployeeName],[Id],[StartDate]
FROM (
    SELECT Value, ColumnName
    FROM @tbl ) x
PIVOT (
MAX(Value)
FOR ColumnName in ([EmployeeName],[Id],[StartDate])) p
```

And sample data:

```
DECLARE @tbl table
(
ID INT,
Columnname VARCHAR(50),
[Value] NVARCHAR(max)
)

INSERT INTO @tbl
(
    ID,
    Columnname,
    Value
)
VALUES
  (01, 'EmployeeName', 'Tommy')
, (02, 'Id', '5A477EC0-F6A9-4BD4-9B69-D4C8253E8E75')
, (03, 'StartDate', 'Jun 27 2015 10:25PM')
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
EmployeeName                   Id                                    StartDate
Tommy           5A477EC0-F6A9-4BD4-9B69-D4C8253E8E75            Jun 27 2015 10:25PM
```

**UPDATE:**
You've got this error as you put `varchar` values such as `5A477EC0-F6A9-4BD4-9B69-D4C8253E8E75`, `Tommy` into  field `StartDate` of type `datetime`. So consider to avoid inserting not Date values into field `StartDate`.

Comment: It was my mistake, there is another step to this process where in I try to put these values in another table which has column type of DateTime and that's where it will error out. I will update the problem statement above

Comment: Thank you, I believe the error shows up because I am trying to put nvarchar value of  'Jun 27 2015 10:25PM' into Datetime column, is there a way to select it in the right format so that it is converted to date as part of the insert statement?

Answer (score 0):

I would use conditional aggregation :

```
insert into MyTable ([EmployeeName], [Id], [StartDate]) 
    select max(case when Columnname = 'EmployeeName' then value end) as EmployeeName,
           max(case when Columnname = 'Id' then value end) as Id,
           max(case when Columnname = 'StartDate' then value end) as StartDate
    from (select e.*, row_number() over (partition by Columnname order by id) as seq
          from Employee e
         ) e
    group by seq;
```